# traverse nested tagnames - selenium automation using webDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-ide, ui-automation, selenium-firefoxdriver

Friends,

I have a situation where I need to click on a dropdown list and select any value displayed.
The dropdown is identified by the following piece of code

```
<select id="order_unit_line_rate_806782_is_addenda_enabled" class="selects_for_487886" onchange="select_addendum(806782, this);dateShowMemory(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, '806782');" uniqueattr="Dynamic Site Accelerator / Dynamic Site Accelerator / Additional Usage Commitment / drop down" name="order_unit_line_rate[806782][is_addenda_enabled]">
    <option value="0" uniqueattr="Dynamic Site Accelerator / Dynamic Site Accelerator / Additional Usage Commitment / Fee"> Fee </option>
    <option value="1" uniqueattr="Dynamic Site Accelerator / Dynamic Site Accelerator / Additional Usage Commitment / See Attached Addendum"> See Attached Addendum </option>
```

where **the
    "select" and 
    "option" tags are in a nested hierarchy**. i am able to click on the dropdown list and display the items by doing this

```
List<WebElement> dropDownLists = driver.findElements(By.tagName("select"));
for (WebElement l : dropDownLists) { 
    if (l.getAttribute("uniqueattr").equalsIgnoreCase("Dynamic Site Accelerator / Dynamic Site Accelerator / Additional Usage Commitment / drop down")) {
              l.click();
    } // end if
} // end for
```

But I am unable to traverse further to click on the options in the dropdown :(.

This is what i tried but which is not working

```
List<WebElement> newList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
for (WebElement ll : newList) {
    if (ll.getAttribute("uniqueattr").equalsIgnoreCase("Dynamic Site Accelerator / Dynamic Site Accelerator / Additional Usage Commitment / Straight Line Commitment")) {
        ll.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the label, index or value of the option you want to click like this

```
List<WebElement> dropDownLists = driver.findElements(By.tagName("select"));
for (WebElement l : dropDownLists) 
{ 
    List<WebElement> newList = l.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    for (WebElement ll : newList) 
    {
            if (ll.getAttribute("uniqueattr").equalsIgnoreCase("Dynamic Site Accelerator / Dynamic Site Accelerator / Additional Usage Commitment / Straight Line Commitment")) 
            {
                SelectElement select = new SelectElement(l);
                select.SelectByValue(ll.getAttribute("value"));
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats what the [Select](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) is for..

do something like:

```
    Select dropDown = new Select(dropDownElement);
    for (WebElement option : dropDown .getOptions()){
        if(!option.isSelected()){
            option.click();
        }
    }
```